# Consumable in app purchase windows store

Tags: in-app-purchase, windows-store-apps

I want users to buy a product as many times as they want. e.g gold coins, bonus points etc. Is it possible to specify the the LicenseDuration="0" so that as soon as the user buys it the points are added to users account and the product is ready to be bought again. I'm doing it the following way, it works fine in the simulator mode:

```
<Product ProductId="sp75" LicenseDuration="0">
            <MarketData xml:lang="en-us">
                <Name>ServerPoints75</Name>
                <Price>1.99</Price>
                <CurrencySymbol>$</CurrencySymbol>
                <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            </MarketData>        
</Product>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consumables are not supported by the built-in in-app purchase support at this time.

You may be able to accomplish what you want with a 3rd party commerce provider. May be worth doing a search on Bing for some of the major payment providers.

Hope that helps.

For more info on Windows Store app development, register for [Generation App](http://bit.ly/gd30tolaunch).

Answer (score 1):

You are limited in the number of in-app purchases, so that's not even a viable workaround if you were considering it : )

Check out the PayPal API for consumables, subscriptions, etc. There's a specific Win8 wrapper on github for it:

http://paypal.github.com/Windows8SDK/